# Can we use nedb with NativeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nedb

I'm working on application where I have desktop app and mobile app which is mostly in offline mode.

I have done for Electron based desktop app with nedb, angular2 and TypeScript. But I'm not sure that nedb can be setup with NativeScript with Ionic or not.

Thanks all,

Comment: If it npm module you probably can implement https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-npm-modules-and-nativescript-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nedb relays on **crypto** module which is currently not supported by NativeScript. So basically at this very moment, you can not use **nedb** with a NativeScript application. More information [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/195)